# Can I share weights between keras layers but have other parameters differ?

Tags: deep-learning, keras

In keras, is it possible to share weights between two layers, but to have other parameters differ? Consider the following (admittedly a bit contrived) example:

```
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, input_shape=input_shape, padding='same')
conv2 = Conv2D(64, 3, input_shape=input_shape, padding='valid')
```

Notice that the layers are identical except for the `padding`. Can I get keras to use the same weights for both? (i.e. also train the network accordingly?)

I've looked at the keras doc, and the [section on shared layers](https://keras.io/getting-started/functional-api-guide/#shared-layers) seems to imply that sharing works only if the layers are completely identical.

Comment: Have you tried it? Theoretically, convolution layers with the same kernel size and same product of input-output channels will have weight tensors with the same dimensions.

Comment: @E_net4 Indeed the dimensions match, my question is how to get keras to share the weights (i.e. I would like to try it, I just don't know how :))

Answer (score 19, accepted):

To my knowledge, this cannot be done by the common "API level" of Keras usage.
However, if you dig a bit deeper, there are some (ugly) ways to share the weights.

First of all, the weights of the `Conv2D` layers are created inside the `build()` function, by calling `add_weight()`:

```py
    self.kernel = self.add_weight(shape=kernel_shape,
                                  initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                  name='kernel',
                                  regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                                  constraint=self.kernel_constraint)
```

For your provided usage (i.e., default `trainable`/`constraint`/`regularizer`/`initializer`), `add_weight()` does nothing special but appending the weight variables to `_trainable_weights`:

```py
    weight = K.variable(initializer(shape), dtype=dtype, name=name)
    ...
        self._trainable_weights.append(weight)
```

Finally, since `build()` is only called inside `__call__()` if the layer hasn't been built, shared weights between layers can be created by:

1. Call `conv1.build()` to initialize the `conv1.kernel` and `conv1.bias` variables to be shared.
2. Call `conv2.build()` to initialize the layer.
3. Replace `conv2.kernel` and `conv2.bias` by `conv1.kernel` and `conv1.bias`.
4. Remove `conv2.kernel` and `conv2.bias` from `conv2._trainable_weights`.
5. Append `conv1.kernel` and `conv1.bias` to `conv2._trainable_weights`.
6. Finish model definition. Here `conv2.__call__()` will be called; however, since `conv2` has already been built, the weights are not going to be re-initialized.

The following code snippet may be helpful:

```py
def create_shared_weights(conv1, conv2, input_shape):
    with K.name_scope(conv1.name):
        conv1.build(input_shape)
    with K.name_scope(conv2.name):
        conv2.build(input_shape)
    conv2.kernel = conv1.kernel
    conv2.bias = conv1.bias
    conv2._trainable_weights = []
    conv2._trainable_weights.append(conv2.kernel)
    conv2._trainable_weights.append(conv2.bias)

# check if weights are successfully shared
input_img = Input(shape=(299, 299, 3))
conv1 = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='same')
conv2 = Conv2D(64, 3, padding='valid')
create_shared_weights(conv1, conv2, input_img._keras_shape)
print(conv2.weights == conv1.weights)  # True

# check if weights are equal after model fitting
left = conv1(input_img)
right = conv2(input_img)
left = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(left)
right = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(right)
merged = concatenate([left, right])
output = Dense(1)(merged)
model = Model(input_img, output)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam')

X = np.random.rand(5, 299, 299, 3)
Y = np.random.randint(2, size=5)
model.fit(X, Y)
print([np.all(w1 == w2) for w1, w2 in zip(conv1.get_weights(), conv2.get_weights())])  # [True, True]
```

One drawback of this hacky weight-sharing is that the weights will not remain shared after model saving/loading. This will not affect prediction, but it may be problematic if you want to load the trained model for further fine-tuning.

Comment: Interesting! I didn't know it could be done like this. Although the inability to save the sharing is an issue, I would like to be able to finetune the model.

Comment: I haven't tried, but I think you can use `model.save_weights()` to save the weight arrays only instead of the entire model object. For finetuning, just recreate the model with the same code, and then call `model.load_weights()`.

Comment: Are you sure this works? I get OOM and I can tell from `tensorflow/core/common_runtime/bfc_allocator.cc` that tf is actually trying to allocate multiple copies of the weights

Comment: My issue was due to custom layers. If those are the weights you are sharing is better to pass them during initialization of the layer. That solved my OOM problem

Comment: Well if you are writing custom layers then of course you shouldn't use this solution. Re-writing the layer is much cleaner. As I said, this is merely a quick hack.