# How to share weights between two conv layers with different dilation rate in keras?

Tags: python, deep-learning, keras

Suppose I have two layers:

```
x1 = Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 1, 1), activation='relu', dilation_rate=2)(x)
x2 = Conv3D(16, kernel_size=(3, 1, 1), activation='relu', dilation_rate=3)(x)
```

Is there a way to share weights between these two layers?

Comment: I think you can try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45245396/1531463). I haven't tested on `Conv3D` and `dilation_rate`, but I assume that they should be the same.