# How to share convolution kernel and rotation in keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, keras

i get solution to share convolution kernel by coping the kernels
([share weights between keras layers but have other parameters differ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45245396/can-i-share-weights-between-keras-layers-but-have-other-parameters-differ)). But in this solution, we just able to copy the kernels. 
How to share the kernels with kernel rotation in keras?

Comment: What do you mean by sharing rotation?

Comment: let's say we have two layers. According to the solution linked above, we just able to copy **conv2.kernel = conv1.kernel**. But in my case, i want to flip 90 degree of the first layer's kernel and copy to the second layer's kernel. So, how to do like this in keras?
**conv2.kernel = rotate(conv1.kernel)**